# Is it Possible to Get Multiple Data Type using a Single Query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a **ViewModel** looks like this :

```
public int AllRecords { get; set; }
public int IsActiveRecords { get; set; }
public int IsDeletedRecords { get; set; }
public List<Setup_Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

[image]

**Is it possible to write a single query using Entity Framework to get these data 
from database ?**

If not , then what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Are the first 3 properties the count of all, active and deleted `Setup_Country` items?

Comment: yes. this will count the records specified.

Comment: Why not just `var countries = db.Setup_Countries.ToList(); var model = new ViewModel { Countries = countries, AllRecords = countries.Count, IsDeletedRecords = countries.Count(x => x.IsDeleted), ... }`

Comment: I am afraid that it will query  database 4 times..... @Stephen Muecke

Comment: No it wont - it only queries the database once - in the first line - the others are referencing the in-memory set

Comment: Then the answer posted below is the right one ?

Comment: The first one makes 1 call, the 2nd makes 4 calls to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the multiplicity you want here? you can fill this ViewModel in like this:

```
model = new MyViewModel();
model.Countries = db.SetupCountry.ToList();
model.AllRecords  = model.Countries.Count();
model.IsActiveRecords = model.Countries.Count(c => c.IsActive);
model.IsDeletedRecords = model.Countries.Count(c => c.IsDeleted);
```

As Stephen Muecke Has noted in the comments, this will query the db only once.

Or, if you want a one-liner,

```
model = new MyViewModel{
    Countries = db.SetupCountry.ToList(),
    AllRecords = db.SetupCountry.Count(),
    IsActiveRecords = db.SetupCountry.Count(c => c.IsActive),
    IsDeletedRecords = db.SetupCountry.Count(c => c.IsDeleted),
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me which one is  the best way ?

Comment: First one, since it's hutting the db only once and is relying on the memory for operations, it's way more efficient.